# How do I generate a bunch of checkboxes from a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models `User` and `Category` that have a HABTM association.

I would like to generate checkboxes from a collection of `Category` items on my view, and have them associated with the `current_user`.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

P.S. I know that I can do the equivalent for a dropdown menu with `options_from_collection_for_select`. I also know that Rails has a `checkbox_tag` helper. But not quite sure how to do both of them. I know I can just do it manually with an each loop or something, but am wondering if there is something native to Rails 3 that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check out [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) or [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

They have helpers to write your forms more easily, also to handle simple associations.

E.g. in `simple_form` you can just write

```
= simple_form_for @user do
  = f.association :categories, :as => :check_boxes
```

In `form_tastic` you would write

```
= simple_form_for @user do
  = f.input :categories, :as => :check_boxes
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow...I was wondering what the benefits of Simple_Form were, but I am glad that you have pointed this out. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection_select and feed it the options. Assuming you have a form builder wrapped around a user instance, you can do something like this:

```
form_for current_user do |f|
f.collection_select(
  :category_ids,            # the param key, so params[:user][:category_ids]
  f.object.categories,      # the collection of items in the list
  :id,                      # option value
  :name                     # option string
)
end
```

You may want to pass the `:multiple => true` option on the end if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just generates a dropdown menu - not a series of HABTM checkboxes.

Comment: Right, sorry I misread your question. There's no built-in helper for looping over checkboxes.